# Login into database with hibernate dynamically

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, authentication, dao

I have to make an application that has a login to enter the database as admin, without having to use the username and password parameters of the configuration file, but I can not get it, could you help me?

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static void configureHibernateUtil(String user, String pass) {
    try {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("/dao/hibernate.cfg.xml"); //hibernate config xml file name
        String newUserName = null, newPassword = null;//set them as per your needs
        cfg.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", newPassword);
        cfg.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", newUserName);
        //In next line you just tell Hibernate which classes are you going to query

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
        sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        System.err.println("Ocurrió un error en la inicialización de la SessionFactory: " + he);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(he);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method parameter `user` and `pass` **does NOT** replace the properties of `cfg`. So the method does not work. Here is the amended code:

```
public static void configureHibernateUtil(String user, String pass) {
    try {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("/dao/hibernate.cfg.xml"); //hibernate config xml file name
        //String newUserName = null, newPassword = null;//set them as per your needs
        cfg.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", pass);
        cfg.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", user);
        //In next line you just tell Hibernate which classes are you going to query

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
        sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        System.err.println("Ocurrió un error en la inicialización de la SessionFactory: " + he);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(he);
    }
}
```